# TChart is truncated when resizing

Tags: delphi, teechart, rad-studio

There is a project on Delphi 7. It uses a customized component of TChart (Steema). The chart is located on the frame. When the frame is resized, the chart scales correctly.
After migrating the project to Delphi 10.3 Rio, there are problems with the chart.

Now when resizing the frame up, the chart does not change size. In addition, the chart is redrawn incorrectly. The chart on the right looks truncated. I am using new TChart components for Rio.

Why is the chart truncated? There were no issues with the old TChart components.
[image]

Comment: Does `Chart.Refresh` in `Frame.OnResize` solves this issue?

Comment: No, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: It is not fast to reproduce your problem - TeeChart on Panel with alClient resizes as intended in 10.2 after Panel resizing

Comment: I solved this problem. I did not report an important point in the question. Directly on the frame is a chart inherited from TChart. This chart has overridden the Paint method. I researched the code. The following methods are called there: GetClipRgn, CreateRectRgn, SelectClipRgn, DeleteObject. I found an extra call to the DeleteObject method and removed it. This helped solve the problem.